# Reference: jfrog artifactory could not validate router error

Tags: centos7, artifactory

I have tried everyone's suggestions and I still get a failure. This is on a new installation of artifactory: jfrog-artifactory-oss-7.4.1-linux.tar.gz. This is on a local CentOS VM.

```
2020-04-18T11:53:25.305Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [a88f4f6ce96d65bb] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:141 ] [pool-13-thread-1 ] - Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error while trying to connect to local router at address ‘http://localhost:8046/access’: Connect to localhost:8046 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

```
hostname -i
172.16.217.147

more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 centos7 centos7.example.com localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

172.16.217.147 artifactory-master
```

system.yaml

```
shared:
  node:
    ip: 172.16.217.147
```

This is from access-service.log:

```
2020-04-18T11:52:19.789Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7fbbd46f40602f6b] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:65 ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Starting gRPC Server on port 8045

2020-04-18T11:52:20.072Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7fbbd46f40602f6b] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:84 ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - gRPC Server started, listening on 8045

2020-04-18T11:52:21.995Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [7fbbd46f40602f6b] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:59    ] [ocalhost-startStop-2] - Started AccessApplication in 11.711 seconds (JVM running for 13.514)

2020-04-18T11:52:29.093Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [7b2c676f76c7ef43] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:141      ] [pool-6-thread-2     ] - Retry 20 Elapsed 9.54 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again

2020-04-18T11:52:34.119Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [7b2c676f76c7ef43] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:141      ] [pool-6-thread-2     ] - Retry 30 Elapsed 14.57 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
```

Comment: Can you provide a few more details? What CentOS version? What were the steps taken? What did you run?

Comment: Can you also provide access logs? I suspect access may have failed  to start  for some reason.

Comment: Brand new installation of artifactory as of Friday on a CentOS 7 VM.  I ran this:  ./artifactory.sh  I am running as root user from the command line - not as a service.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with CentOS 7 as when I do a new install on my Mac - with the same version there are no issues at all.

Comment: Is what you shared above your full system.yaml? If no please share the full file. What ports are listening? Check with e.g. netstat -ntlp

Comment: @JoelWerginz, were you able to resolve this? We started having the same issue last week after a reboot. Our admin has to kill the processes and then start the service manually (systemctl start artifactory.service). It then starts fine. We upgraded to the latest (7.29.8-72908900) just to see if that would help, but no joy.